# Regex or Wildcard in Kotlin's when statement?

Tags: regex, wildcard, kotlin

I'm working on a RESTful app in Kotlin and for the router, I'm using a when statement, as it's the most readable and good looking conditional.

Is there a way to use Regex or a wildcard in the when statement for a string?

(So that URIs like "/article/get/" would all be passed to the same controller)

The structure of my router is as follows:

```
when(uri) {
    "some/url" -> return SomeController(config).someAction(session)
}
```

Comment: 1. There is no wildcard in "/article/get/" so it only matches itself which makes it a bit hard to understand your question. (i.e. what kind of URI matching do you really want/need?) 2. Putting verbs like "get" in RESTful APIs is typically frowned upon; the HTTP methods are the verbs and resources should be referenceable with the same address regardless of the verb. 3. Have you considered using a RESTful framework with routing built-in? e.g. Jersey.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

```
import kotlin.text.regex

val regex1 = Regex( /* pattern */ )
val regex2 = Regex( /* pattern */ )
/* etc */

when {
    regex1.matches(uri) -> /* do stuff */
    regex2.matches(uri) -> /* do stuff */
    /* etc */
}
```

You could also use [`containsMatchIn`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/contains-match-in.html) if that suits your needs better than [`matches`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/matches.html).

**Explanation:**

The test expression of a [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#when) statement is optional.  If no test expression is included, then the `when` statement functions like an `if-else if` chain, where the [`whenCondition`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#whenCondition) of each [`whenEntry`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#whenEntry) shall independently evaluate to a boolean.

---

EDIT:

So I thought about it for awhile, and I came up with a different approach that might be closer to what you want.

```
import kotlin.text.regex

when (RegexWhenArgument(uri)) {
    Regex(/* pattern */) -> /* do stuff */
    Regex(/* pattern */) -> /* do stuff */
    /* etc */
}
```

Where `RegexWhenArgument` is minimally defined as:

```
class RegexWhenArgument (val whenArgument: CharSequence) {
    operator fun equals(whenEntry: Regex) = whenEntry.matches(whenArgument)
    override operator fun equals(whenEntry: Any?) = (whenArgument == whenEntry)
}
```

This approach lets you get as close as possible to the "argument-ful" `when` expression syntax.  I think it's about as streamlined and readable as it can be (assuming that you define the `RegexWhenArgument` class elsewhere).

This approach uses something similar to the visitor design pattern in combination with Kotlin's operator overloading to redefine what constitutes a "match" between a `when` expression argument and a `whenEntry`.  If you really wanted to, I suppose you could take this approach a step further and generify `RegexWhenArgument` into a general-purpose `WhenArgument` and `WhenArgumentDecorator` that allows you to specify custom "match" criteria in a `when` expression for any sort of type, not just Regex.

Comment: Thanks mate! This is not perfect, but I guess it's the best option for me right now.

Comment: @JacobS You could use anonymous instances of `Regex` if you don't want the pattern to be visually separated from the `return SomeController` logic, but that might start taking up a lot of horizontal line space inside the `when` block...

Comment: @JacobS. I just edited in another approach that might be closer to what you're looking for...

Comment: This is great! Thank you.

Comment: Anyone else have a problem with with using import kotlin.text.regex? Like I wonder if it was moved

Comment: Unfortunately, the second approach to have a more elegant syntax does not work with Kotlin 1.5. There is a typing issue (RegexWhenArgument is not a Regex).
Anyway, that trick may be error prone in other contexts because RegexWhenArgument::equals was not symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

The typing of the [when](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#when) statement enforces to have compatible types between the *whenSubject* and the *whenEntries*. So we cannot compare a String `whenSubject` with a `Regex` directly.

We can use when with no subject, then branch conditions may be simply boolean expressions.

```
fun main() {
  val uri: String? = "http://my.site.com/a/b/c"

  val res = when {
    uri == null -> "NULL"
    uri == "http://my.site.com/" -> "ROOT"
    uri.startsWith("http://my.site.com/a/") -> "A STUFF"
    uri.matches(Regex("http://my.site.com/b/.*")) -> "B STUFF"
    else -> "DEFAULT"
  }
  /* do stuff */
}
```

Alternatively, we can emulate a kind of when+regex with a dedicated class and few helper functions.

```
fun main() {
  val uri: String? = "http://my.site.com/a/b/c"

  val res2 = when(matching(uri)) {
    null -> "NULL"
    matchesLiteral("http://my.site.com/") -> "ROOT"
    matchesRegex("http://my.site.com/a/.*") -> "A STUFF"
    else -> "DEFAULT"
  }
  /* do stuff */
}

class MatchLiteralOrPattern(val value: String, val isPattern: Boolean) {
    override fun hashCode(): Int = value.hashCode()
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (other !is MatchLiteralOrPattern) return false
        if (isPattern && !other.isPattern) return Regex(this.value).matches(other.value)
        if (!isPattern && other.isPattern) return Regex(other.value).matches(this.value)
        return value == other.value
    }
}
fun matching(whenSubject: String?) = whenSubject?.let { MatchLiteralOrPattern(it, false) }
fun matchesLiteral(value: String) = MatchLiteralOrPattern(value, false)
fun matchesRegex(value: String) = MatchLiteralOrPattern(value, true)
```

Comment: In your alternative solution you didn't override hashCode(). Can you update your answer?

Comment: I added an implementation of hashCode(). But I am not sure it is really useful here. I don't see any scenario where it would be used.
I hope my answer can help people to figure how the when syntax works in Kotlin 1.5. But in my case, I used when with no subject because I think my solution based on MatchLiteralOrPattern was too complex.

Answer (score 2):

```kotlin
operator fun Regex.contains(text: CharSequence): Boolean = this.matches(text)

when("Alex") {
  in Regex(".+lex") -> { println("ends with lex") }
}
```

Copied from here:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/using-regex-in-a-when/1794/6?u=cyberavater

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following on the [kotlin playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/) and it seems to work as expected.

```kotlin
class WhenArgument (val whenArg: CharSequence) {
    override operator fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return when (other) {
            is Regex -> other.matches(whenArg)
            else -> whenArg.equals(other)
        }
    }
}

fun what(target: String): String {
    return when (WhenArgument(target) as Any) {
        Regex("source-.*") -> "${target} is-a-source"
        Regex(".*-foo") -> "${target} is-a-foo"
        "target-fool" -> "${target} is-the-target-fool"
        else -> "nothing"
    }
}

fun main() {
    println(what("target-foo"))
    println(what("source-foo"))
    println(what("target-bar"))
    println(what("target-fool"))
}
```

It works around the type compatibility problem by making the 'when' argument of type Any.