# What is the most concise way to include functions or lambdas as conditions in a Kotlin `when` statement (or other branching construct)?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, functional-programming, conditional-statements, control-flow

I'm processing strings, and I came across the [Regex or Wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41271363/1413900) answer: that one can put regular expressions in a `when` statement with a custom class that overrides equals. While this does effectively use the type system to shoehorn syntactic sugar into the `when` statement, I find the following pretty ugly, and would never do this in code that I intend to share with another developer (quoting [travis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5029307/travis)):

```
import kotlin.text.regex

when (RegexWhenArgument(uri)) {
    Regex(/* pattern */) -> /* do stuff */
    Regex(/* pattern */) -> /* do stuff */
    /* etc */
}
```

Where RegexWhenArgument is minimally defined as:

```
class RegexWhenArgument (val whenArgument: CharSequence) {
    operator fun equals(whenEntry: Regex) = whenEntry.matches(whenArgument)
    override operator fun equals(whenEntry: Any?) = (whenArgument == whenEntry)
}
```

(*end quote*)

I think it would be much more readable to pass an arg to `when` and then reference functions that operate on the type of the arg. For a contrived example:

```
// local declaration
val startsWithFn: (String) -> Boolean = {s -> s.startsWith("fn:")}

when(givenString) {
    ::startsWithHelp -> printHelp()
    startsWithFn -> println("Hello, ${givenString.substring(3)}!")
}

// package level function
fun startsWithHelp(s:String) = s.startsWith("help", true)
```

But of course, this code doesn't compile. Is there a way to do this that's readable, maintainable, and concise? Maybe using Streams? What would an experienced Kotlin developer do?

Comment: I really, really would do a chain of ifs.  I really do think that looks and reads just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few solutions to your problem. I will start with the simple ones and then move on to the more complex.

---

### When without argument

[Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html) says:

> `when` can also be used as a replacement for an `if`-`else if` chain. If no
>   argument is supplied, the branch conditions are simply boolean
>   expressions, and a branch is executed when its condition is true

**Use case:**

```
when {
    startsWithHelp(givenString) -> printHelp()
    startsWithFn(givenString) -> println("Hello, ${givenString.substring(3)}!")
}
```

**Pros**:

1. Doesn't require any additional code
2. Easy to understand

**Cons**:

1. Boilerplate `(givenString)`

---

### Argument wrapper which overrides equals

The required wrapper is similar to `RegexWhenArgument`, but instead of checking `Regex` it invokes `(String) -> Boolean`. There is nothing special about `String`, so I will use `<T>`.

**Wrapper function:**

```
fun <T> whenArg(arg: T) = object {
    override fun equals(other: Any?) =
        if (other is Function1<*, *>) 
            (other as Function1<T, Boolean>)(arg)
        else arg == other
}
```

**Use case:**

```
when (whenArg(givenString)) {
    ::startsWithHelp -> printHelp()
    startsWithFn -> println("Hello, ${givenString.substring(3)}!")
}
```

**Pros:**

1. Functions can be used in `when` branches
2. Very easy to understand
3. Requires only one simple wrapper function

**Cons:**

1. Easy to forget to wrap an argument
2. The function of the wrong type can be accidentally used in a branch condition

**Note**: this solution and the next one allows using functions combination, which can be created by these extensions:

```
infix fun <T> ((T) -> Boolean).and(other: ((T) -> Boolean)) = { it: T -> invoke(it) && other(it) }
infix fun <T> ((T) -> Boolean).or(other: ((T) -> Boolean)) = { it: T -> invoke(it) || other(it) }
operator fun <T> ((T) -> Boolean).not() = { it: T -> !invoke(it) }
```

---

### DSL-based `when` analog

In Kotlin DSL can be used not only for building objects but for creating custom program flow structures as well.

**Source code:**

```
@DslMarker
annotation class WhichDsl

// This object is used for preventing client code from creating nested
// branches. You can omit it if you need them, but I highly recommend
// not to do this because nested branches may be confusing. 
@WhichDsl
object WhichCase

// R type parameter represents a type of expression result
@WhichDsl
class Which<T, R>(val arg: T) {
    // R? is not used here because R can be nullable itself 
    var result: Holder<R>? = null

    inline operator fun ((T) -> Boolean).invoke(code: WhichCase.() -> R) {
        if (result == null && invoke(arg)) result = Holder(code(WhichCase))
    }

    // else analog
    inline fun other(code: WhichCase.() -> R) = result?.element ?: code(WhichCase)
}

data class Holder<out T>(val element: T)

inline fun <T, R> which(arg: T, @BuilderInference code: Which<T, R>.() -> R) =
    Which<T, R>(arg).code()
```

**Statement use case:**

```
which(givenString) {
    ::startsWithHelp { printHelp() }
    startsWithFn { println("Hello, ${givenString.substring(3)}!") }
}
```

**Expression use case:**

```
val int = which(givenString) {
    ::startsWithHelp { 0 }
    startsWithFn { 1 }
    other { error("Unknown command: $givenString") }
}
```

**Pros:**

1. Customizable syntax
2. New features can be added
3. Functions which works only with some argument types can be added
4. Nested branches can be enabled
5. No boilerplate
6. Function types are checked at compile-time
7. Easy to read

**Cons:**

1. Requires a few helper classes and functions
2. Usage of experimental `@BuilderInference` (it can be replaced with explicit type declaration for expressions and separate method for statements)
3. New syntax learning may take some time

**Extensions examples:**

```
inline fun <R> Which<*, R>.orThrow(message: () -> String) =
    other { throw NoWhenBranchMatchedException(message()) }

val <R> Which<*, R>.orThrow get() = orThrow { "No branch matches to $arg" }

inline fun <T, R> Which<T, R>.branch(condition: (T) -> Boolean, code: WhichCase.() -> R) =
    condition(code)

inline fun <T, R> Which<T, R>.case(value: T, code: WhichCase.() -> R) =
    branch({ it == value }, code)

fun <T : CharSequence, R> Which<T, R>.regex(regex: Regex, code: WhichCase.() -> R) =
    branch({ regex.matches(it) }, code)

fun <T : Comparable<T>, R> Which<T, R>.range(range: ClosedRange<T>, code: WhichCase.() -> R) =
    branch({ it in range }, code)

inline fun <T> Which<T, *>.sideBranch(condition: (T) -> Boolean, code: WhichCase.() -> Unit) {
    if (condition(arg)) code(WhichCase)
}

fun <T> Which<T, *>.sideCase(value: T, code: WhichCase.() -> Unit) =
    sideBranch({ it == value }, code)

inline fun <R> Which<*, R>.dropResult(condition: WhichCase.(R) -> Boolean = { _ -> true }) {
    result?.let { (element) ->
        if (WhichCase.condition(element)) result = null
    }
}

inline fun <T, R> Which<T, R>.subWhich(condition: (T) -> Boolean, code: Which<T, R>.() -> R) =
    branch(condition) {
    which(this@subBranch.arg, code)
}
```